# printing the comparison between two codes

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, debugging

What is the best way to compare two codes side by side while the differences and similarity between two codes are color-coded and finally be able to print the result? I was able to use visual studio in order to open the codes and compare them but there is no way to print the results.

I will appreciate to get any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode has a built-in tool called FileMerge.

1. Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> FileMerge

[image: Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> FileMerge]

2. Choose your files to compare, then click <kbd>Compare</kbd>

[image: Compare files, choose Left and Right, then click Compare]

3. See differences

[image: Left and Right panels with color-coded differences, with third panel below showing result after setting an Action for each difference]

There's some other nice services like [Diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) that let you do this online too.

Comment: Thanks it is very useful tool but I can't still use it to print the whole code with the highlighted compared parts.